# Адресация сайта без переменных

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток. Представим себе адресацию сайта:

```
http://site.ru/?theme=questions
http://site.ru/?theme=tags
http://site.ru/?theme=users
http://site.ru/?theme=badges
```

Тема в разделе, скажем, какие-то деления на контент еще, то дополнительная переменная

```
http://site.ru/?theme=tags&tags=tema_1
http://site.ru/?theme=tags&tags=tema_2
```

Все просто и понятно, определяем значение переменной, выводим нужный контент на сайте. теперь по поводу непонятного:

```
http://site.ru/questions/
http://site.ru/tags/
http://site.ru/users/
http://site.ru/badges/
```

Далее начинается головоломка, если нужно делить контент еще...

```
http://site.ru/questions/vopros_1/
http://site.ru/questions/vopros_2/
http://site.ru/questions/vopros_3/
```

Первое, что приходит в голову, - отдельная директория, и туда еще нужно пихать .htaccess. Но тогда, скажем, придется делать ссылку на таблицу стилей привязанную к адресу сайта, а не директории.

Второе - адрес строки разбивается на части. Определенная часть равна определенной переменной.

Третье - я чего-то не знаю 8-(

1. Как максимально просто приравнять адрес из строчки адреса к переменной на php? можно ли это сделать только на php?
2. Есть ли какие то плюсы во втором описанном мною способе?
3. Может, я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: О mod_rewrite слухи не доходили? =)

Comment: гениально. начну копать в этом направлении. спасибо.

Comment: ну да... я просто помолчу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот мой пример, реализован через парсинг REQUEST_URI

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
# Если не файл
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
# Если не директория
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Запускаем index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
function ParseURL_ModRewrite()
{
    //Чиста URI
    $uri=preg_replace('#[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+$#i', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $get_reqs=explode('/', $uri, 20);

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($get_reqs);$i++)
    {
        if($get_reqs[$i]=='' && ($i+1)==sizeof($get_reqs))
            break;

        $_GET['value'.($i+1)]=$get_reqs[$i];    
    }
}
ParseURL_ModRewrite();

//Вывод на экран всех параметров GET
print_r($_GET);
?>
```